# Creating a multi-dimensional array using JavaScript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following elements (below), and would like to create an array of the form:

```
[ 
  ["name": "Tim", "age":24, "hair":"black"], 
  ["name": "Tim", "age":344, "hair":"red"], 
  ["name": "Tim", "age":24, "hair":"brown"], 
]

<div class="person">
    <div class="name">Tim</div>
    <div class="name">24</div>
    <div class="name">black</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="name">Tim</div>
    <div class="name">34</div>
    <div class="name">red</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <div class="name">David</div>
    <div class="name">56</div>
    <div class="name">brown</div>
</div>
```

My attempt:

```
 var arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.person'), 
      row => Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('.name'), cell => cell.textContent)
     );
```

But this gives me an array of the type:

```
 [["Tim","24","black"],["Tim","34","red"],["David","56","brown"]]
```

Comment: you mean `{"name": "Tim", "age":24, "hair":"black"}`, an array of objects?

Comment: Where were you expecting `age` and `hair` to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class called Person and pass necessary arguments to it. As you already have arguments as `["Tim","24","black"]`, using spread operator would do the trick.

```js
function Person(name, age, hair) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.hair = hair;
}

var arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.person'),
  row => {
    var args = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('.name'), cell => cell.textContent);
    return new Person(...args)
  });

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Tim</div>
  <div class="name">24</div>
  <div class="name">black</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Tim</div>
  <div class="name">34</div>
  <div class="name">red</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">David</div>
  <div class="name">56</div>
  <div class="name">brown</div>
</div>
```

#### ES5

As correctly pointed by @[charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl), `Array.from`, arror functions (`=>`) and spread operator (`...`) have limited compatibility. For older browsers you should consider following approach.

```js
function Person(name, age, hair) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.hair = hair;
}

var persons = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.person'));

var arr = persons.map(function(person) {
  var props = [].slice.call(person.querySelectorAll('.name'));
  var args = props.map(function(el) {
    return el.textContent;
  });

  return new Person(args[0], args[1], args[2])
})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Tim</div>
  <div class="name">24</div>
  <div class="name">black</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Tim</div>
  <div class="name">34</div>
  <div class="name">red</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">David</div>
  <div class="name">56</div>
  <div class="name">brown</div>
</div>
```

Comment: same with `from()`

Comment: @charlietfl Please check the update. Feel free to point out any issue. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh When I send the json string to server the person object detected is ["Tim", "24", "black"], instead of a dictionary which is what I need e.g ["name": "Tim", "age":"24", "hair":"black"]. How would you modify the code above to get the result that I need?

Comment: @tim `["name": "Tim", "age":"24", "hair":"black"]` is not a valid JSON. You can create it but will be a patch work and will hive you lot of issues in data-manipulation. When you say dictionary, it means `{key: value}` and not `[key: value]`

Comment: @tim above code already gives `key:value` pair. Can you please clarify what is the issue?

Comment: When I get the array of person objects, json encode it and then send it to the server.  I then decode the json string using php, I no longer get the key value pair but an array of  ["Tim", "24", "black"],  ["David", "34", "red"],  etc...

Comment: Apologies as I'm not qualified in PHP. You can try using `JSON.stringify`. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

given an array like:

```
const arr = [["Tim","24","black"],["Tim","34","red"],["David","56","brown"]];
```

you could change it to an array of objects using `map`:

```
const result = arr.map(row => ({name: row.name, age:row.age, colour: row.colour}));
```

or equivalently:

```
const result = arr.map(([name, age, colour]) => ({name, age, colour}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return array of objects as result where each object is one `.person` element.

```js
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.person');
var result = Array.from(elms, function(e) {
  return {
    name: e.children[0].textContent,
    age: e.children[1].textContent,
    hair: e.children[2].textContent
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Tim</div>
  <div class="name">24</div>
  <div class="name">black</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Tim</div>
  <div class="name">34</div>
  <div class="name">red</div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">David</div>
  <div class="name">56</div>
  <div class="name">brown</div>
</div>
```